# Краши после обновления

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift3

Залил новую версию 1.3, ничего не изменив в проекте, посыпались краши... Не могу разобраться. Помогите плиз где и что искать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первый

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000028
 Raw Text

0 libsystem_malloc.dylib    szone_free + 2944

1   libsystem_malloc.dylib  szone_free + 1744

2
CoreFoundation  CFRelease + 1088

3   CoreUI  -[CUIStructuredThemeStore renditionWithKey:usingKeySignature:] + 1600

4
CoreUI  -[CUICatalog _storageRefForRendition:representsODRContent:] + 104

5   CoreUI  -[CUICatalog namedLookupWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 188

6   UIKit   __98-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:]_block_invoke + 424

7   UIKit   -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:] + 212

8   UIKit   -[UIImageAsset imageWithTraitCollection:] + 404

9   UIKit   -[UIImageView _resolveImageForTrait:] + 460

10  UIKit   -[UIImageView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 212

11  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

12  UIKit   -[UIControl _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 80

13  UIKit   -[UINavigationButton _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 88

14  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

15  UIKit   -[UINavigationBar _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 68

16  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

17  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

18  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

19  UIKit   __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 152

20  UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 504

21  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1784

22  UIKit   -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 664

23  UIKit   -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 252

24  UIKit   -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48

25  UIKit   -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3456

26  UIKit   -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1672

27  UIKit   -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168

28  FrontBoardServices  -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184

29  FrontBoardServices
-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56

30  CoreFoundation  **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24

31  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540

32  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 724

33  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384

34  UIKit   -[UIApplication _run] + 460

35 UIKit    UIApplicationMain + 204

36  Back    AppDelegate.swift line 15
main

37  libdispatch.dylib   (Missing)

Второй

```
#0 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
```

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000
 Raw Text

0   libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 28

1   CoreFoundation  CFEqual + 340

2   CoreFoundation  __NSCacheKeyEqual + 12

3   libcache.dylib  _entry_get_optionally_checking_collisions + 164

4   libcache.dylib  cache_get_and_retain + 132

5   CoreFoundation  -[NSCache objectForKey:] + 68

6   CoreUI  -[CUIStructuredThemeStore_canGetRenditionWithKey:isFPO:lookForSubstitutions:] + 360

7   CoreUI  +[CUICatalog _resolvedRenditionKeyFromThemeRef:withBaseKey:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:memoryClass:graphicsClass:graphicsFallBackOrder:] + 1204

8   CoreUI  -[CUICatalog namedLookupWithName:scaleFactor:deviceIdiom:deviceSubtype:sizeClassHorizontal:sizeClassVertical:] + 148

9   UIKit   __98-[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:]_block_invoke + 424

10  UIKit   -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:scale:idiom:subtype:cachingOptions:sizeClassPair:attachCatalogImage:] + 212

11  UIKit   -[_UIAssetManager imageNamed:withTrait:] + 528

12  UIKit   _UIImageWithNameAndTraitCollection + 96

13  UIKit   +[UIImage(UIImagePrivate) _kitImageNamed:withTrait:] + 36

14  UIKit   CreateScrollIndicator + 260

15  UIKit   -[UIScrollView _adjustScrollerIndicators:alwaysShowingThem:] + 200

16  UIKit   -[UIScrollView _didChangeFromIdiom:onScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 344

17  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didChangeFromIdiomOnScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 180

18  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1472

19  UIKit   -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 92

20  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

21  UIKit   __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 152

22  UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 504

23  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1792

24  UIKit   -[_UIParallaxDimmingView didMoveToWindow] + 180

25  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1496

26  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

27  UIKit   __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 152

28  UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 504

29  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1792

30  UIKit   __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 + 1684

31  UIKit   +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 80

32  UIKit   __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 252

33  UIKit   +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:] + 220

34  UIKit   -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] + 1036

35  UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 3520

36  UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688

37  UIKit   -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60

38  UIKit   -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208

39  UIKit   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 644

40  QuartzCore  -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148

41  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292

42  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32

43  QuartzCore  CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252

44  QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::commit() + 516

45  UIKit   afterCACommitHandler + 180

46  CoreFoundation__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32

47  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372

48  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 928

49  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384

50  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 180

51  UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 204

52  Back    AppDelegate.swift line 15
main

53  libdyld.dylib   start + 4

Третий

```
#0Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
```

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x000001aa08ac4049
 Raw Text

0   libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend + 28

1   UIKit   -[UIImageView _resolveImageForTrait:] + 404

2   UIKit   -[UIImageView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 212

3   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

4   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

5   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

6   UIKit   -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 92

7   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

8   UIKit   -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 92

9   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

10  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

11  UIKit   __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 152

12  UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 504

13  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1784

14  UIKit   __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 + 1412

15  UIKit   +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 80

16  UIKit   __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 260

17  UIKit   +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:] + 220

18  UIKit   -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] + 1060

19  UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 3544

20  UIKit   -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688

21  UIKit   -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60

22  UIKit   -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208

23  UIKit   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656

24  QuartzCore  -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148

25  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292

26  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32

27  QuartzCore  CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252

28  QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::commit() + 512

29  UIKit   _afterCACommitHandler + 180

30  CoreFoundation **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 32

31  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372

32  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 928

33  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384

34  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 180

35  UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 204

36  Back    AppDelegate.swift line 15
main

37  libdispatch.dylib   (Missing)

Четвертый

```
#0  Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
```

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000
 Raw Text

0  libobjc.A.dylib  objc_msgSend + 28

1   UIKit   -[UIView dealloc] + 1240

2   UIKit   -[UILabel dealloc] + 144

3   libobjc.A.dylib (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 508

4  CoreFoundation   _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28

5   UIKit   _prepareForCAFlush + 352

6  UIKit    _afterCACommitHandler + 160

7   CoreFoundation **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 32

8   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372

9   CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 928

10  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384

11  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 180

12  UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 204

13  Back    AppDelegate.swift line 15
main

14  libdispatch.dylib   (Missing)

Пятый

```
#0  Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
```

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000028
 Raw Text

0   libsystem_malloc.dylib  szone_free_definite_size + 2804

1   libsystem_malloc.dylib  szone_free_definite_size + 1252

2   CoreGraphics    CGGStackRestore + 40

3  CoreGraphics CGContextRestoreGState + 48

4   UIKit   -[UIImage drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:] + 1452

5   UIKit   -[UIImageView _setImageViewContents:] + 1440

6   UIKit   -[UIImageView _updateState] + 616

7   UIKit   +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 80

8   UIKit   -[UIImageView _updateImageViewForOldImage:newImage:] + 620

9   UIKit   -[UIImageView _resolveImageForTrait:] + 872

10  UIKit   -[UIImageView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 212

11  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

12  UIKit   -[UIControl _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 80

13  UIKit   -[UINavigationButton _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 88

14  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

15  UIKit   -[UINavigationBar _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 68

16  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

17  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

18  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 760

19  UIKit   __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 152

20  UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 504

21  UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1792

22  UIKit   -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 664

23  UIKit   -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 264

24  UIKit   -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 48

25  UIKit   -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3456

26  UIKit   -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1660

27  UIKit   -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168

28  FrontBoardServices  -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184

29  FrontBoardServices  -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56

30  CoreFoundation  **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24

31  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540

32  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 724

33  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384

34  UIKit   -[UIApplication _run] + 460

35  UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 204

36  Back    AppDelegate.swift line 15
main

37  libdyld.dylib   start + 4

Шестой

```
#0  Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
```

EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000
 Raw Text

0  libobjc.A.dylib  objc_msgSend + 28

1   libcache.dylib  _entry_remove + 184

2   libcache.dylib  cache_remove_with_block + 200

3   CoreFoundation  __NSCacheApplicationDidEnterBackgroundCallBack + 124

4  CoreFoundation   **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 20

5   CoreFoundation  _CFXRegistrationPost + 396

6  CoreFoundation   ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 60

7   CoreFoundation  -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1532

8   CoreFoundation  _CFXNotificationPost + 368

9   Foundation  -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 68

10  UIKit   __47-[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground]_block_invoke + 320

11  UIKit   +[UIViewController _performWithoutDeferringTransitions:] + 128

12  UIKit   -[UIApplication _applicationDidEnterBackground] + 100

13  UIKit   -[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:] + 700

14  UIKit   -[UIApplication _handleApplicationLifecycleEventWithScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 448

15  UIKit   __70-[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 152

16  UIKit   -[UIApplication scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 708

17  FrontBoardServices  -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184

18  FrontBoardServices  -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56

19  CoreFoundation  **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24

20  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540

21  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 724

22  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384

23  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 180

24  UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 204

25  Back    AppDelegate.swift line 15
main

26  libdyld.dylib   start + 4

Comment: 1.3 - это версия приложения или какой-то библиотеки?

Comment: Это версия приложения

Comment: как я вижу ни один креш не трейсит к вашему коду, т.е. все что вы видите это внутренние проблемы ios. я бы на вашем месте не заморачивался, по крайней мере пока какой тоткреш не случится хотя бы 10-20 раз